# Measurement of topological spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-order, topological-field-theory, topological-insulators

How do you measure the topological spin of an anyon? So how could an experimental setup look like? Is topological spin an observable at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The topological spin $h$ of an anyon (a quasi-hole in a FQH state) is the exponent in the Green function of the quasi-hole along the edge of the FQH state
[see eq.(61) in my review paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3268 ], which can be measured by the I-V curve: $I\propto V^{4h-1}$ in the tunnelling experiments between FQH edges.